# Pulling up a blank page for use with a translucent background in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I'm putting the following snippet in the manifest for the activity to make the background translucent.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

That does exactly what it supposed to and displays whatever the user had pulled up before running my app (like the list of applications). Is there anyway to make just the users background display behind my app and not whatever they had pulled up before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this instead 
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper">`

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I couldn't find this.